# `LinearSolve` in arbitrary precision has a sudden change in performance as the size of a problem is gradually increased

Tags: linear-algebra, arbitrary-precision

It is expected that calculations in arbitrary precision are much slower than in machine precision. However, `LinearSolve` has an unexpected behavior: there is a sudden change in its speed when I gradually increase the size of the equation for the following problem. All data in the following has 34 digits of precision by setting `$MinPrecision = 34`.

I am solving five coupled nonlinear PDEs by Newton's method, and increase the grid size gradually. If the grid size is $(N_x,N_y)=(22,22)$, it takes 0.18 seconds to solve a linear equation. However, if the grid size is $(N_x,N_y)=(23,23)$, it takes 1222 seconds to solve a linear equation. The data for the linear equations can be downloaded at the following address:

https://github.com/renphysics/hello-world/blob/master/lhsrhs22.m

https://github.com/renphysics/hello-world/blob/master/lhsrhs23.m

```
{lhs, rhs} = << lhsrhs22.m;
(* Grid size is 22x22. The matrix size 2420x2420. *)

LinearSolve[lhs, rhs] // AbsoluteTiming
(* It takes 0.18 seconds *)
```

```
{lhs, rhs} = << lhsrhs23.m;
(* Grid size is 23x23. The matrix size is 2645x2645. *)

LinearSolve[lhs, rhs] // AbsoluteTiming
(* It takes 1222 seconds. *)
```

If we randomly generate a linear equation in the size of $2645\times 2645$, it takes only 2.2 seconds to solve it. (It takes 0.13 seconds in machine precision.) This is significantly faster than the above calculation in the same size. (If we randomly generate a linear equation in the size of $2420\times 2420$, it takes 1.9 seconds to solve it.)

```
lhs = RandomReal[1, {2645, 2645}, WorkingPrecision -> 34];
rhs = RandomReal[1, {2645}, WorkingPrecision -> 34];
LinearSolve[lhs, rhs] // AbsoluteTiming
(* It takes 2.2 seconds. *)
```

How to explain this peculiar behavior, and is it possible to speed up `LinearSolve` for arbitrary precision calculations?